# What is the difference between the numeric keys and the normal digit keys?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I want to know what is the difference between the numeric keys and the digit keys available on PC and Laptop. Some tricks only numeric keys works simple digit keys don't.

For example, creating folder con and a nameless folder we have to use the numeric keys and then the task accomplish but not when we use digit keys. I tried some Googling but did not get sufficient info.

Answer (score 0):

they have different [virtual keycode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). it's an implementation issue with the application or maybe a wanted behavior. :)